# Simple but Impossible single MYSQL One to Many Query

Tags: mysql, database, select, join, relational-division

**`Staff` Table**

```
ID Name   Gender
1  John   Male
2  Adam   Male
3  Joella Female
```

**`Food` Table**

```
ID StaffID Name
1  1       Eggs
2  1       Bacon
3  1       Toast
4  2       Eggs
5  2       Bacon
6  3       Toast
```

I need the name of the MALE staff member who has consumed both eggs and toast.
  The answer should be John, but everytime I used an AND clause it is zero results because it is looking at the same "row field".  Using an OR returns the incorrect results.

I tried left join, standard join, and a few others.

```
SELECT field from table left join table2 on table.field=table2.field 
where field ='eggs' && field = 'toast' && gender = 'male'
```

The trick to this is I am trying to do this in a single query.

Comment: I think you should be using AND in place of && in your query.

Comment: in table2.field are you joining by id or staffid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`field` cannot be `eggs` and `toast` at the same time, so join on the same table again

```
SELECT field from table left join table2 ON table.field = table2.field
left join table2 table22 ON table.field = table22.field
WHERE table2.field = 'eggs' AND table22.field = 'toast' && gender = 'male'
```

I'm also pretty sure that you don't want to join `ON` "field," but on some other column like the staffID.

Comment: @BillKarwin you're absolutely right; there is no need for a `LEFT JOIN` in this case (and it is nullified anyway)

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.  I never had to do a second join on the same table within a query. First time for everything!

Answer (score 2):

Group by staff member and then filter the resulting groups for those that satisfy the desired criteria:

```sql
SELECT   Staff.Name
FROM     Staff JOIN Food ON Food.StaffID = Staff.ID
WHERE    Food.Name IN ('Eggs', 'Toast')
     AND Staff.Gender = 'Male'
GROUP BY Staff.ID
HAVING   COUNT(Food.ID) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, count(Food.id) AS foodcount
FROM Staff
LEFT JOIN Food ON Staff.id = Food.StaffID
WHERE Food.Name IN ('eggs', 'toast') AND gender = 'male'
GROUP BY Staff.id
HAVING foodcount = 2;
```

Comment: Don't you want count distinct in the event the eggs or toast are duplicated instead of one of each?

Comment: OP never said if `food.id,food.staffid` is a unique tuple or not. if it isn't, then yeah, count(distinct) would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

you can go with `JOIN` syntax, or with `IN` syntax

```
SELECT name from staf
where
ID in (select StaffId from food where Name='egg') and
ID in (select StaffId from food where Name='toast') and
gender = 'male'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.name from staff_table s join food_table f1 on f1.staff_id=s.id join food_table f2 on f2.staff_id=s.id where f1.name='Toast' and f2.name='Eggs' and s.gender='Male'
```